# Error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured..?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have just started django and I have stuck in an error that I can't find the solution. As my first project in django is: To Do list web app.

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class ToDo(models.Model):
added_date = models.DateTimeField()
text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

When I run this code it show me these error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Have you read the django poll tutorial app  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: No, I did not read it, thank you for telling me. Can you tell me where can I focus in the tutorial to fix my error?

Comment: I would suggest to do first all the poll app tutorial to understand how django works in general and the you can build your application.